# Is there a way to set lockscreen text on WP without using the livetile?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I want to set the notification area of the lockscreen, as found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207048(v=vs.105).aspx

The only way to do this that I found was to set the WideBackgroundContect of the main tile. This ofcourse makes the main tile flip which I don't want.

So the question remains: how can I set the notification text on the lockscreen without letting my main tile flip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to put content where the calendar test normally goes, the only way is to set the back content. I agree this is limiting for apps when you do not want the tile to flip.